# CDI Producer(s) Different Versions of same class

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

I have a JEE6 simple producer class that produces a SimpleDateFromat object:

```
public class myProducer {

    @Produces public SimpleDateFormat produceASimpleDateFormat(final InjectionPoint injectionPoint)
    {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

I want to either:

1. create a new producer and somehow be able to dictate in the class what  DateFormat gets injected where or...
2. edit my existing Producer to produce a different SimpleDateFormat based on  a passed parameter.

How best should I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a use for qualifiers.

You can either

```
@Produces
@TypeA
public SimpleDateFormat produceTypeAFormat() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
}

@Produces
@TypeB
public SimpleDateFormat produceTypeBFormat() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Or something more dynamic where you read the injection point to read the qualifier w/ a content, such as `@Format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` where you can read the qualifier on the injectionpoint.